# Kend Grid Pass Additional Data via js to Read Action in Server Binding

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In **Kendo Grid** how to **pass additional data** from **javascript** to Read Action if I'm using **Server binding**.

```html
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()            
            .Sort(sort => sort.Add(o => o.MaxDelay).Descending())
            .PageSize(500))
```

When I use Ajax binding the option is there, fetchParameter is the javascript function.

```html
.Read(read => read.Action("Load", "Home").Data("fetchParameter"))
```

The documentation only provides a way to hardcore these parameters : 
https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/server-binding#configuration-Pass

I've checked online all the answers online are for Ajax binding.

Comment: I guess the question is do the `additional parameters` ever change if not then add them in to the read method as attributes and pass the values either in the viewbag or the page model. Otherwise use the most appropriate binding strategy for the problem. I think the `Server` binding can be a bit misleading as any method that gets `remote` data can be considered server binding but is expecting the results as the expected collection  e.g. `List<T>` as opposed to `DataSourceResult` object.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't pass additionnal data using JavaScript to the Read action when the grid is using server binding. This is because the grid is generated and the data is fetch only once when the view is rendered server-side before client code (JavaScript) can be executed. To pass additional data using JavaScript you must use Ajax binding.